# Why is double considered a global name?

Tags: python, module, nameerror

I've created the code below, when I import the module and attempt to run it I received the following error:

```
>>> import aiyoo
>>> aiyoo.bixidist(1,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "aiyoo.py", line 50, in bixidist
    currentDist = dist(X,Y,c)
  File "aiyoo.py", line 39, in dist
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow((X-getLat(i)),2)+math.pow((Y-getLong(i)),2))
  File "aiyoo.py", line 28, in getLat
    xmlLat = double(xmlLat)
NameError: global name 'double' is not defined
```

The double function was used in order to convert the unicode output from the XML into a double as input for the functions to follow. So I do not understand why, it is considered to be a name when the aiyoo module is imported.

Here is the module, which was named aiyoo.py:

```
import math
import urllib2
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
file = urllib2.urlopen('http://profil.bixi.ca/data/bikeStations.xml')
data = file.read()
file.close()
dom = parseString(data)

#this is how you get the data
def getID(i):
    xmlID = dom.getElementsByTagName('id')[i].toxml()
    xmlID = xmlID.replace('<id>','').replace('</id>','')
    xmlID = int(xmlID)
    return xmlID

def getLat(i):
    xmlLat = dom.getElementsByTagName('lat')[i].toxml()
    xmlLat = xmlLat.replace('<lat>','').replace('</lat>','')
    xmlLat = double(xmlLat)
    return xmlLat

def getLong(i):
    xmlLong = dom.getElementsByTagName('long')[i].toxml()
    xmlLong = xmlLong.replace('<long>','').replace('</long>','')    
    xmlLong = double(xmlLong)
    return xmlLong

#this is how we find the distance for a given station
def dist(X,Y,i):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow((X-getLat(i)),2)+math.pow((Y-getLong(i)),2))
    return distance

#this is how we find the closest station
def bixidist(X,Y):
     #counter for the lowest
    lowDist = 100000
    lowIndex = 0
    c = 0
    end = len(dom.getElementsByTagName('name'))
    for c in range(0,end):
            currentDist = dist(X,Y,c)
            if currentDist < lowDist:
                lowIndex = c
                lowDist = currentDist
    return getID(lowIndex)
```

Answer (score 3):

As answered by others, `double` is not a built-in type in python. You have to use, `float` instead. Floating point is implemented using double in C [ [ref](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) ].

And as to the main part of your question i.e. "why the double considered a global name?", when you use a `variable-name` say `double`, which is not found in local context, the next lookup is in global context. It is then, if it is not found even in global context, the exception is raised, saying `NameError: global name 'double' is not defined`.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `double` type in Python. And if you look at the error it complains that it can't find anything named `double`. The floating-point type in Python is named `float`.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `xmlLat = float(xmlLat)`

Python `float` is same as `double` of other languages. ( 64 bit )

http://codepad.org/AayFYhEd

Answer (score 0):

Like the other 2 answers so far have said, Python doesn't have a `double` variable type, instead it has `float`.

Now for the question in your title and possibly another source of confusion for you. The reason the interpreter is saying "NameError: global name 'double' is not defined" is because of how Python searches for names of functions, variables, objects, etc. This pattern is described by Python's namespace and scope rules. Because you tried to call the nonexistent function `Double` from within a function without qualifying it (ie. `SomeObject.Double(x)`), Python first looks for an object of that name in the local namespace (namespace of the current function that is running), then the local namespace of the enclosing functions, then the global namespace, and finally the built-in namespace. The reason the interpreter gave you that message is because of the order of Python's search for the definition of `Double()`. global namespace was the last place it checked before looking for it in the built-ins (which are Python's coding, not yours, so I guess it wouldn't make sense for the interpreter to say "NameError: built-in name 'double' is not defined"). At least I think this is what's going on. I'm still not a very seasoned programmer, so I trust someone else will correct me if I got something wrong.